# Post and Get results from asp.net API with angularjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I'm pulling data from a web service created with asp.net.When i try the api with postman i get data from the API but when i post with angular is get nothing from the server. I'm thinking may how i'm posting it is wrong

```
.controller('bill_ctrl',['$scope','$http','$location','$base64','$ionicPopup',function($scope,$http,$location,$base64,$ionicPopup){

        $scope.getcustomerstatement = JSON.stringify({
                                        "account_number": "060218204068",
                                        "start_date": "2010-01-01",
                                        "end_date": "2017-09-01"
                                        });

            console.log($scope.getcustomerstatement);

        var url= 'http://myserver.com/GetCustomerStatementAccount'

        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : url,
          data    : $scope.getcustomerstatement,

     })
      .success(function(data, config, headers, status) {
            console.log(data)
        }).error(function(error){
        console.log(error)
        })
```

Comment: aside from the obvious (probably) typo (double `//` in url), when you can get data in postman but not a browser, it's almost always CORS.

Comment: You shouldn't need the JSON.stringify call. Also, success is deprecated.